# GCP AI Notebook can't access storage bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

New to GCP. Trying to load a saved model file into an AI Platform notebook. Tried several approaches without success.

Most obvious approach seemed to be to set the value of a variable to the path copied from storage:

`model_path = "gs://<my-bucket>/models/3B/export/1600635833/saved_model.pb"`

Results: `OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: (the above path)`

I know I can connect to the bucket and retrieve contents because I downloaded a csv file from the bucket and printed out the contents.

Comment: For context - I'm working with this collab notebook:
https://colab.research.google.com/github/google-research/text-to-text-transfer-transformer/blob/master/notebooks/t5-trivia.ipynb#scrollTo=1TpeMFGhaN7r

Answer (score 0):

According to the GCP documentation [enter here](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/working-with-cloud-storage#cloud-storage-setup) , you are able to access Cloud Storage. This page will guide to using Cloud Storage with AI Platform Training.

Comment: The link doesn't work. And, as I noted in my posted question, I am able to connect to Cloud Storage and retrieve a csv file from my bucket. What I can't do is provide a path that works for a function that takes the path as an argument.

Comment: Link corrected. As per this [doc](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22480#issuecomment-439099157) I can see that they got the same error and I suspect that your .pb file need to regenerated in correct ways, please follow the [create-pb-file](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model).

Comment: Thanks. I'll check out that doc and see if it fixes the issue. Will add a comment with the results.

Answer (score 0):

`OSError` to me sounds like you are trying to access GCS bucket with a regular file system which do not support looking at GCS. (Example: Python open() function)

To access files in GCS I recommend you use the Client Libraries. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries

Another option for testing is to try to connect to SSH and use [gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) command.

**Note**: I assume `<my-bucket>` was edited to replace your real GCS bucket name.

Comment: Thanks. I do have the client libraries installed. Everything I am trying to do is on an AI Notebook VM. And, yes, you are correct in your assumption that I used <my-bucket> to represent the value for  the bucket I'm trying to access.